# Is Sybok a Romulan?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan, romulan, the-final-frontier

Mr. Spock's half-brother Sybok is emotional and basically crazy. He doesn't follow the Vulcan's way of logic so does that mean he's a Romulan?

Comment: No... Spock and Sybok share the same father, but I believe Sybok's mother was Vulcan... (can't find a reference though so I might well be imagining it)

Comment: According to the movie, she was a Vulcan princess

Comment: No. He's an emotional Vulcan

Comment: Too lazy to make a real answer with references and such. Sybock was a Vulcan. He rejected logic and embraced emotion. He is sort of similar to the V'tosh Ka'tur but more radical as they did not reject logic.

Comment: I'm a Canadian who doesn't like Hockey.  Does that make me American?

Comment: The problem with citing references here is that doing so would necessitate rewatching Star Trek 5.  You really want to do that to people?

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt What does God need with a rewatch?

Comment: @starpilotsix Only if you own more than one firearm.

Comment: @starpilotsix Yes. More specifically, from North America.

Comment: @starpilotsix, Once, down the American path you have taken a step, forever it will rule you.

Comment: There were plans for season 5 of *Enterprise* to reveal that [T'Pol was half-Romulan](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/T%27Pol), as an explanation for her emotional behaviour.

Answer (score 15):

## No, Sybok was Vulcan.

Sybok was the son of Sarek and an unnamed [Vulcan princess](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vulcan_23rd_century_princess#Princess_001). He is *biologically* %100 Vulcan.

Sybok did not want to follow the teachings of Surak. This is indeed what the caused the Romulans to split from the Vulcans in the first place, but **Vulcans and Romulans [are *physically* different as well](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/5581/33591)**, as detailed in the linked answer.

So while Sybok may *emotionally* have been more Romulan than Vulcan, there  is a biological difference between the two species, and Sybok is a Vulcan.

Answer (score 3):

**Sybok was a vulcan**

He was technically a Vulcan, no denial but you could say he acted like a Romulan, or rather he acted like *Those That March Under The Raptors's Wings* (ancestors of the Romulans that defied Surak) but Romulans stopped being Vulcans a long time ago when they started evolving and breeding so that they got their V shaped foreheads.

Comment: isn't it raptors wings?

Comment: Oh right sorry will edit it